# Can't create procedure phpMyAdmin MYSQL error

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mariadb

Help!! I'm stuck, I don't know what's wrong.
I'm working on MySql but it won't create procedure, I'm out of ideas.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sc_new_ord(IN inscid INT, IN incust_id INT, IN indeltype_id INT, IN duty_it INT, IN delcost INT, OUT ttmount INT, OUT outordid INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE ord_id INT;
  DECLARE total INT;
  
  INSERT INTO tbl_orders (customer_id, ship_type_id, rate_id, status) VALUES
         (incust_id, indeltype_id, duty_it,0);
  
  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO inscid;

  INSERT INTO tbl_ord_det (ord_id,inv_id, item, qtty, price)
  SELECT ord_id, tbl_inventory.Inv_id, tbl_inventory.Item, tbl_shp_ct.qtty,
              COALESCE(NULLIF(tbl_inventory.Offer_Price, 0), tbl_inventory.Price) AS price
  FROM        tbl_shp_ct
  INNER JOIN  tbl_inventory
                ON tbl_shp_ct.inv_id = tbl_inventory.Inv_id
  WHERE tbl_shp_ct.sc_id = inscid AND tbl_shp_ct.buy_now;
    -- total amount
  UPDATE tbl_orders
  SET    tt_mnt = (SELECT SUM(price * qtty)FROM tbl_ord_det WHERE ord_id = ord_id)
  WHERE  ord_id = ord_id;
  CALL sc_empty (inscid);
  SELECT (SUM(price * qtty) FROM tbl_ord_det WHERE  ord_id = ord_id) as tt INTO total;
  SELECT total, delcost, (total+delcost) INTO ttmount;
  SELECT ord_id INTO outordid;
END
```

Full Error: MySQL said: Documentation

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: Why are u using <p> and </br> tags in procedure??

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax. the <p> and <br> were a mistake, sorry

Comment: Are u using mysql or mariadb?

Comment: I'm working phpMyadmin

Comment: why u are inserting id into this **SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO inscid;** as inscid is input parameter of procedure function?

Comment: post your full error which contains the line something like ".... for the right syntax near....." that shows which line have the error..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql database then try as per below and share error if still getting-

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sc_new_ord(IN inscid INT, IN incust_id INT, IN indeltype_id INT, IN duty_it INT, IN delcost INT, OUT ttmount INT, OUT outordid INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE ord_id INT;
  DECLARE total INT;

  INSERT INTO tbl_orders (customer_id, ship_type_id, rate_id, status) VALUES
         (incust_id, indeltype_id, duty_it,0);

  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO inscid;

  INSERT INTO tbl_ord_det (ord_id,inv_id, item, qtty, price)
  SELECT ord_id, tbl_inventory.Inv_id, tbl_inventory.Item, tbl_shp_ct.qtty,
              COALESCE(NULLIF(tbl_inventory.Offer_Price, 0), tbl_inventory.Price) AS price
  FROM        tbl_shp_ct
  INNER JOIN  tbl_inventory
                ON tbl_shp_ct.inv_id = tbl_inventory.Inv_id
  WHERE tbl_shp_ct.sc_id = inscid AND tbl_shp_ct.buy_now;
    -- total amount
  UPDATE tbl_orders
  SET    tt_mnt = (SELECT SUM(price * qtty)FROM tbl_ord_det WHERE ord_id = ord_id)
  WHERE  ord_id = ord_id;
  CALL sc_empty (inscid);
  SELECT (SUM(price * qtty) FROM tbl_ord_det WHERE  ord_id = ord_id) as tt INTO total;
  SELECT total, delcost, (total+delcost) INTO ttmount;
  SELECT ord_id INTO outordid;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: The error for above: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM tbl_ord_det WHERE  ord_id = ord_id) as tt INTO total;
  SELECT total, delc' at line 22

Comment: may you let me know what is 2nd ord_id here in "WHERE ord_id = ord_id" as I am not getting any variable above in code.

Comment: The 2nd ord_id is key from table tbl_orders and it is a foreign key in tbl_ord_det

Comment: "SELECT (SUM(price * qtty) FROM tbl_ord_det WHERE  ord_id = ord_id) as tt INTO total;" not clear what you want to do here..this is not a valid query...try to execute it on mysql prompt and check if it gives you result.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
SELECT (SUM(price * qtty) FROM tbl_ord_det WHERE  ord_id = ord_id) as tt INTO total;
```

to

```
SELECT SUM(price * qtty) as tt FROM tbl_ord_det WHERE  ord_id = ord_id INTO total;
```

by moving `as tt` to the right place.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25a842